# Why is it that my Materialize collapsible menu doesn't work after updating with f:ajax (JSF)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf-2, materialize

I am working with JSF 2.2 and Materialize. I need to update a collapsible dynamic list when the user sends one basic form with `h:form`, `h:commandButton` and `f:ajax` labels.

This is the code for the form sent by the user:

```
<h:form>
    ...
    <h:commandButton value="send!" action="#{...}">
        <f:ajax render="@form pgMenu" execute="@form"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

And this code represents the menu to be updated:

```
<h:panelGroup id="pgMenu">
    <ul class="collapsible myList">
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty bean.variable}">
            <li class="bold item-li"><a class="collapsible-header item-a">New</a>
                <div class="collapsible-body">
                    <ul>
                        <a href="page1.xhtml"><li class="li-izquierda">New 1</li></a>
                        <a href="page2.xhtml"><li class="li-izquierda">New 2</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <li class="bold item-li"><a class="collapsible-header item-a">Fases</a>
            <div class="collapsible-body">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#"><li class="li-izquierda">Planeación</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li class="li-izquierda">Otra mas</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="bold item-li"><a class="collapsible-header item-a waves-teal">JavaScript</a>
            <div class="collapsible-body">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#"><li class="li-izquierda">Collapsible</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li class="li-izquierda">Dialogs</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</h:panelGroup>
```

My problem is that when `pgMenu`is updated, the menu js behavior freezes.

The next images show the menu before and after sending the form (I am clicking options).

Before update

[image]

After update

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Are you executing some extra javascript/jquery after page loads? It seems that when the component gets updated it loses its javascript behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

After each update, your DOM structure is changing, therefore you need to destroy previous instance of Collapsible class:

```
instance.destroy();
```

And then, after your new structure is rendered, you need to reinitialize Collapsible:

```
var newElement = document.getElementById('YOUR_COLLAPSIBLE_CONTAINER');
var instance = new M.Collapsible(newElement, {YOUR OPTIONS});
```

I'm afraid that is your only option, when using materialize-css library.